# Filtering mongodb records based on query parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm writing a REST API in Express.js to retrieve some records from a mongo database. To get a set of records I use a standard GET request:

```
GET localhost:3000/api/books
```

Now to implement filters I've used the `express-api-queryhandler`. The code looks like this:

```
routes.use(queryHandler.filter());

[...]

.get((req: any, res: Response) => {
    Book.find(req.where, req.fields, req.options, (err: any, orders: any) => {
        res.status(200).json(books);
    });
});
```

So now when I want to retrieve a specific element I can write e.g.:

```
GET localhost:3000/api/books?name=Harry%20Potter
```

But what would be the best way to implement (greater/lower than) GT, GTE, LT, LTE functions? Are there any good libraries for Node.js? I've only found the where function in `Loopback` documentation but is it ok to use Loopback with Express?

I could write everything manually but it wouldn't be a nice solution. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've edited the filter.js file in the earlier mentioned package so that it works with gt, lt, gte, lte. It looks safe but maybe there is a better option with more validation?

```
function filter (query, skip) {
    var filters = {};
    var k;

    var SKIP_KEYS = [
        'fields',
        'limit',
        'offset',
        'sort'
    ].concat(skip);

    for (k in query) {
        if (SKIP_KEYS.indexOf(k) === -1) {
            var param = query[k];
            // Added part
            if(param.startsWith("gte_")) param = {"$gte": param.substr(4)}
            else if(param.startsWith("lte_")) param = {"$lte": param.substr(4)}
            else if(param.startsWith("gt_")) param = {"$gt": param.substr(3)}
            else if(param.startsWith("lt_")) param = {"$lt": param.substr(3)}
            // End of added part

            console.log(param);
            filters[k] = param;
        }
    }

    return filters;
}

module.exports = function (options) {
    var o = options || {};

    return function (req, res, next) {
        req.where = filter(req.query, o.skip);
        next();
    };
};
```